# Flashing icons (crashing gui) in OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, spotlight, crash

Since yesterday the icons on the top-right of my macbook (yosemite) are constantly flashing. Looking at system.log it seems like the gui is crashing and restarting every second. Here is a copy of the [crash report](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3UCRATqZ).

This started happening quite suddenly, I didn't perform any system changed. The only thing I did recently is install a printer driver, but I doubt that that is related.

```
Jeroens-MBP:log jeroen$ tail -fn0 system.log
Jan 18 11:44:35 Jeroens-MBP Spotlight[341]: spot: agent checkin
Jan 18 11:44:35 Jeroens-MBP SystemUIServer[549]: Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x7f8441e06120 </System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Clock.menu> (not loaded)
Jan 18 11:44:35 Jeroens-MBP SystemUIServer[549]: Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x7f8441d0a530 </System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Volume.menu> (not loaded)
Jan 18 11:44:35 Jeroens-MBP backupd[136]: Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain NULL)
Jan 18 11:44:35 Jeroens-MBP SystemUIServer[549]: *** WARNING: Method convertRectToBase: in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. 
Jan 18 11:44:35 Jeroens-MBP SystemUIServer[549]: *** WARNING: Method convertRectFromBase: in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. 
Jan 18 11:44:37 Jeroens-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.ReportCrash[552]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.ReportCrash
Jan 18 11:44:38 Jeroens-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent[549]): Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Jan 18 11:44:38 Jeroens-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent): Service only ran for 2 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 8 seconds.
Jan 18 11:44:38 Jeroens-MBP ReportCrash[552]: Saved crash report for SystemUIServer[549] version 1.7 (410) to /Users/jeroen/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SystemUIServer_2015-01-18-114438_Jeroens-MacBook-Pro.crash
Jan 18 11:44:38 Jeroens-MBP ReportCrash[552]: Removing excessive log: file:///Users/jeroen/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SystemUIServer_2015-01-18-114110_Jeroens-MacBook-Pro.crash
```

With Problem (no icons showing)

[image: no icons]

as it should be (all showing)

[image: showing]

Comment: we need a copy of this /Users/jeroen/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SystemUIServer_2015-01-18-114438_Jeroens-MacBook-Pro.crash

Comment: Because there are so many crash repots, the original one got automatically cleaned but [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3UCRATqZ) is another one (they are all the same)

Comment: here you go Thread 8 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: ICANotificationPrivateQueue
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00007fff91893acf objc_release + 15
1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00007fff9189291f (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 575

Comment: Any guess to which application is causing this?

Comment: hang on getting to it :) it says "anonymous namespace", so can you take a screen shot of that area

Comment: Ok [here](http://imgur.com/XtT8H7s&arV4aJp) are both screenshots (click on the page where it says *first image* and *second image*).

Answer (score 1):

Tracking your problem in Crash report it shows

```
Thread 8 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: ICANotificationPrivateQueue
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff91893acf objc_release + 15
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff9189291f (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 575
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff95cb6272 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 50
```

So one of the existing icons is making problems, my hint is the Volume or the Clock.

One way to find out is to trash them one by one (hold cmd and pull it to the desk top). No worry they can be easily restored from here /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu extras.

Comment: Mmm come to thing of it, that chrome notification icon is new. The thing crashes too soon for me to drag the icon down.

Comment: what Chrome notification?

Comment: ok added your screen shots to your OP. now explain what is the first and second icon, what is the 3d and 4th icon?